# Compare index function with JavaScript function?

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

Is it possible to compare the function of an existing index with an ordinary native function in JavaScript?

For instance, I might create an index with the following code:

```js
r.table('Table').indexCreate('index', document => document.hasFields('field'));
```

I might then, later, wish to determine whether the index has the same function:

```js
document => document.hasFields('field')
```

Using `indexStatus()`, two properties may be able to help with this.

First, `function` is a `Buffer` representing the function, and can be compared with `Buffer`s obtained from other `indexStatus()` objects. However, it's not clear how this could be compared with a native JavaScript function. A new index could be created, and then its `Buffer` compared with the `Buffer` of the existing index, but this would be a messy and performance-impacting workaround.

Second, `query` is a `string` containing a function resembling that which was provided to `indexCreate()`. However, this property seems to be undocumented, and the value is not always exactly the same as the function provided to `indexCreate()`, with changes to variable names and the transformation of arrow functions to function expressions. I've written some rough code which tries to work with this approach, although it's imperfect, given the opaque nature of the rules by which the `query` value is generated by RethinkDB.

Comment: why don't you set a unique name for that index, like "index_field_present"? That way you could just call table.indexList() and instantly see whether it's there.

Comment: Hey @taygetos. The context is that I've written a module which guarantees that databases, tables, and indexes are created, according to a config file. The name of each index is specified by the user in the config file. The user can also change the function at any time, without changing the name. It's for this reason that the module needs to work out whether the index function is, in a sense, up-to-date. If it is, the index can be left as it is, but otherwise the index must be recreated. And, obviously, you don't want to recreate the index if the function is unchanged.